# Global redirect module

Tags: 7, redirection

In Global redirect "Add Canonical Link" and "Set Content Location Header" are off by default.

I am not sure should i turn them on or not.

I have community website with around 5000 nodes.
In webmaster tools i don't have any errors.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to resolve with this module?

Comment: I am trying to figure out should i enable these options. I am trying to do as much good SEO as possible and cant figure out would these options damage, boost or do nothing to website at the moment.

Comment: I meant, what problem are you trying solve by using this module in the first place.

Comment: Well thats good question.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out is this plus or minus enabling canonical to all pages. Also today i noticed i have duplicate title tags in webmasters for taxonomy terms: povrce/povrće. There is only one url, clicking it from webmaster tools i get to same page, but it reports duplicate title tag. No idea whay is it happening now, i have this tag online for few months now.